# Montecarlo - impact of single / double precision

Tags: monte-carlo

I am looking at a paper comparing performance of two pricers: same model (based on Monte Carlo simulation) but one implemented on CPU (C++) and one implemented on GPU (Cuda)

The paper mentions the time taken to execute N paths (let's say 100k paths) in both cases. Additional information:

- CPU implementation relies on double precision, while GPU implementation relies on single precision.
- The pricers use quasi-random generator (rate of convergence close to O(1/N))

To do a "fair" comparison (i.e achieving a similar precision), shouldn't we double the number of paths for GPU pricer (single precision)?

Comment: Can you also add a reference to the paper if it is published and/or available online? This question is hard to answer otherwise. My simple answer would be unless $N\geq 10^8$, it doesn't matter because you generally won't reach to the single precision machine epsilon levels of accuracy without using a large value for $N$.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas the paper is unfortunately not available online, and lacks details. I tried to summarize it the best I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, single precision is not twice as fast as double precision. It will be quite difficult to determine theoretically what speed-up you get by moving from double to single precision; if you wanted to make this fair, you'd have to actually measure the speedup.

Second, for Monte Carlo methods the metric people generally use to determine how "good" an algorithm is is how fast they converge to an answer. Since the exponent (${\cal O}(N^{-1/2})$) is fixed, what matters most is the constant that sits in front of the $N^{-1/2}$, and that is (or should be) independent of the precision with which you do you calculation -- it depends on things such as the proposal distribution, whether you have a simple Metropolis-Hastings or a deferred rejection algorithm, etc.

Comment: Note that for most NVIDIA GPU's, double precision performance is limited to 1/32 of the single precision performance.  This is a marketing move by NVIDIA to force customers who want to do double precision to purchase more expensive GPU's that are marketed for use in HPC instead of gaming GPU's.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: this is true for the maximum FLOPs for consumer GPUs (GeForce). In my experience with heavily memory bound algorithms, I observed a factor of roughly two only between single and double precision, because of doubling the amount of data. The reduced FLOPs (limited by the GPU driver btw) did not have an impact at all.

Comment: I didn't make that point very well. What I wanted to say is that I assume that the algorithm in question does not *only* do floating point calculations, but also other things, and that consequently the overall speed is not determined *exclusively* based on floating point speed.